# Como ativar o cadastro de um usuário por email?

Tags: php, login

Bem, ao se cadastrar o usuário tem seu ATIVO setado para 0, como enviar um e-mail com um link de forma que ao clicar nesse link o usuário atualize o ativo para 1.

Comment: Qual o erro? qual o problema? tente descrever melhor a situação.

Comment: Cara voce não postou muitos detalhes do problemas mais acho que sei o que esta ocorrendo.
Nas funçoes mysql, tipo o mysql_query, era opcional vc enviar ou não a sua variavel de conexão.
Já nas funções mysqli, vc tem que enviar a variavel de conexao se nao da warning, tenta fazer tipo assim:
mysqi_query($sql, $con);

Comment: Verifique se a variável `link` tem a conexão, tbm coloque a parte do código onde vc chama `mysqli_insert_id`

Comment: A variável link tem a conexão.

Comment: E o código do insert?

Comment: Deve ser isso o erro então porque não tenho nada do insert a não ser aquela linha, mas era assim que funcionava antes com mysql.

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver o problema crie uma resposta e explique o que foi necessário fazer, quando tiver um problema diferente da pergunta original é melhor fazer uma nova  adicionar o link desta como referência.

Comment: Certo, vou consertar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu gero um token e salvo ele no meu usuário, depois eu busco na base de dados o usuário que contém esse token, assim você recupera o usuário sem muito trabalho. Para gerar o token eu utilizo os seguintes métodos

```
public function onRegistrationSuccess($user)
{
    $user->setEnabled(false);
    if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
        $user->setConfirmationToken($this->generateToken());
    }

    $this->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
}

public function generateToken()
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($this->getRandomNumber()), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

private function getRandomNumber()
{
    return hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true), true);
}
```

Você pode utilizar openssl troque o método de randomNumber para esse aqui

```
private function getRandomNumber()
{
    $nbBytes = 32;

    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($nbBytes, $strong);

    if (false !== $bytes && true === $strong) {
        return $bytes;
    }

    throw new \Exception('OpenSSL não produziu um número aleatório seguro.');

}
```

Comment: Faço isso na página? $token = generateToken();  e $Numero_Aleatorio =getRandomNumber();

Comment: Mas depois faço o mesmo processo do meu código anterior para enviar isso por email como link?

Comment: realizar o registro você gera o token salva ele no usuário (em uma coluna na tabela usuário) e depois envia esse token para o email do usuário como um link (exemplo.com?token=d8s9dad8as). Quando o usuário clicar no link ele será levado para o seu site, recupere ele do banco, buscando o usuário que possui o mesmo token e ative ele

Comment: @IWannaKnow eu adicionei mais um método para explicar melhor

Comment: Antes de Exception é um "\" mesmo?

Comment: CONSEGUI!!! Mas com a primeira função getRamdomNumber (tem algum problema em utilizá-la?). Essa segunda está com PDO? Está dando erro por causa do public/private e do this.

Comment: Desculpe, não tirei o escopo do método, é que eu utilizo isso em uma abordagem OO, pode remover eles. Sobre a "\" é para pegar o objeto em um namespace global