# Como excluir o cadastro do banco de dados caso o usuário não o ative por e-mail dentro de "X" horas?

Tags: php, mysqli

Bem, ao se cadastrar no site o usuário tem seu ATIVO setado para 0, então com o código que postei na resposta da pergunta do link abaixo eu consigo atualizar o ATIVO para 1: [Como ativar o cadastro de um usuário por email?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29774/como-ativar-o-cadastro-de-um-usu%C3%A1rio-por-email/29836#29836)

Mas se o usuário não ativar os dados eles vão continuar ocupando espaço em meu banco de dados. Então alguém pode simplesmente encher meu banco de emails.

Como excluir esses dados caso o cadastro não seja ativado em determinado tempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pessoal eu não sou programador, **estou no grupo como entusiasta**. Faço perguntas para descobrir o que não sei e para ganhar "insights".

**Consegui resolver a situação desta forma:**

**Primeiro fiz isso:**

Na hora do cadastro eu enviei o **time();** para o campo **data_ts** de minha tabela.

Então quando o usuário tentar logar o código abaixo verifica se o ativo é 0 ou 1. Se for 0 e ainda não tiver passado 24h da hora do cadastro eu peço que ele acesse o e-mail para ativar, se tiver passado 24h ai eu deleto da tabela aquele cadastro:

```
         if ($ativo != 1)
         {      
          $tempo_agora = time();

          if (($tempo_agora - $tempo_cadastro) >= 86400)
          {
          $excluir_cadastro = DBDrop('tabela', "email = '$email'"); 
          //DBDrop é minha função para fazer exclusões

          $erros = "Seu cadastro expirou! Após se alistar você tem até 24h 
                    para acessar seu e-mail e ativar sua conta!
                    Agradecemos a compreensão!";
          }
      else {        
             $erros = "Acesse seu e-mail para validar seu cadastro!";}
    }
```

**Mas depois percebi que não resolvia a situação, pois o usuário podia simplesmente nunca tentar logar, então os dados continuariam no banco. Então fiz essa função (num arquivo separado) para colocar na home page através de um require:**

```
<?php
//Exclui linhas não ativadas em até 24h
function vinte_e_quatro () {

 $tempo_agora = time();

 $query = DBDrop('tabela', "ativo='0' AND (data_ts + 86400) <= '$tempo_agora' "); 

}
?>
```

**Muito contente com o resultado, grato a todos por me orientar!**

Comment: Uma vez que o código acima é o que gerou uma resposta para você, marque-o como resposta!

Comment: Ok, vou marcar!

Answer (score 9):

Você pode criar um script que será executado pelo servidor em determinado momento para remover da tabela os usuários com valor `ativo=0` se o tempo de expiração já tiver sido alcançado. Ou talvez uma aplicação paralela para fazer isso.

Se escolher a primeira opção, você pode usar o [**cron**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) - do Linux - ou o [**agendador de tarefas**](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) - do Windows - para executar o script de verificação.

Comment: Oi, Gustavo, tomei a liberdade de editar sua resposta para deixá-la mais afirmativa e menos interrogante. Adicionei também links para documentação. Dê um confere no guia [answer].

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Eu não sei como linkar php e agendador de tarefas do Windows. Vou ter que estudar sobre isso. Essa resposta que postei é válida? Funciona bem.

Comment: Consegui! :3 uhu

Answer (score 7):

Basta você usar uma query imediatamente antes do verificador que simplesmente delete todos os registros que passaram de determinado tempo, e cujo ativo seja zero.

Se fizer essa query em um arquivo PHP separado, pode usar várias técnicas simultaneamente:

- Chamar este PHP com `require_once` alguma(s) linha(s) antes de fazer a ativação. Isto pode ser feito independentemente e concomitantemente às duas técnicas a seguir, e serve para que o cadastro seja eliminado mesmo que a tarefa agendada não tenha rodado justo naquele momento;
- "executar" este PHP via cron/agendador como já mencionado em outra resposta;
- e se não tiver acesso ao cron ou outra forma de agendamento, colocar um contador que rode este PHP com include em outro PHP que seja costumeiramente acessado no site. Por exemplo, a cada *n* acessos, o PHP inclui o script da query. (pode fazer a todo acesso também, mas por questão de performance geralmente não é necessára a execução a todo o momento).

Comment: Olá Bacco, obrigado por responder. Eu consigo bolar os processos lógicos mentalmente e uma vez que vejo os códigos entendo facilmente, mas não sou programador ainda, então preciso e busco respostas na prática. Sei que ninguém tem obrigação de ficar construindo scripts para mim, por isso mesmo corro atrás, estou estudando, não fico somente esperando tudo pronto. Mas por exemplo, eu não sei como linkar php e agendador de tarefas do Windows, vou ter que estudar sobre isso. Essa resposta que postei é válida? Funcionar funciona...

Comment: @IWannaKnow com o que eu propus, não precisa do agendador. Seria bom vc acrescentar o DB que está usando nas tags da pergunta, pois assim fica melhor dar exemplos. Ao menos o SQL de como eliminar dá pra exemplificar bem, mas para isso seria bom você postar ao menos a estrutura da base de dados na questão também.

Comment: Eu entendi, apenas falei de forma geral que sem códigos eu continuo quebrando a cabeça. Mas eu aprecio porque me orientam sobre o que tenho que buscar e o que tenho que estudar. Acrescentei a tag. Grato.

Comment: Consegui! :3 uhu

Answer (score 2):

Muito simples, você terá que criar um script de automatização que será incluída numa página principal do seu site, toda vez que alguém entrar, vai executar esse script.

Olha só, você ai ter que fazer um campo na tabela do usuário chamado "ultima entrada", e toda vez que o usuário estiver logado, vai ter um script que dê um update nesta tabela com o `time()` atual.

Você cria um script, que vá ficar incluído nas páginas principais da área de cliente do site, ou seja, toda vez que você atualizar a página, sua última entrada vai ser atualizada pra a hora que você atualizou a página, certo?

Agora basta você criar um script que imprima todos os cadastros e comparar a última atualização com o time atual, se tiver mais de 24 hrs(3600 * 24) ele deleta esta conta.

Comment: Obrigado, eu consegui fazer isso ontem. Estou tentando fazer uma cron job agora para que o script só rode de tempos em tempos. Parece simples, ma spor enquanto não está funcionando, dá uma olhada na pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29914/como-fazer-com-que-um-script-em-php-inserido-em-uma-p%C3%A1gina-atrav%C3%A9s-de-um-requir