# Como fazer com que um script em php inserido em uma página através de um "require" rode de tempos em tempos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Nas respostas para pergunta do link abaixo eu postei como consegui excluir do banco de dados as informações do usuário que não ativar em até 24h seu cadastro através do link enviado para seu e-mail:

[Como excluir o cadastro do banco de dados caso o usuário não o ative por e-mail dentro de "X" horas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29837/como-excluir-o-cadastro-do-banco-de-dados-caso-o-usu%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-o-ative-por-e-mail)

Em minha homepage de login coloquei a função

```
$revisa = vinte_e_quatro();
```

Agora toda vez que minha homepage for carregada o script vai rodar.
Como fazer para que ele rode somente uma vez por dia, por **semana...?

**DÚVIDA**

Minha função para checar se o usuário ativou ou não seu cadastro em 24h é essa:

```
require 'config.php';  
require 'connection.php'; 
require 'database.php'; 
<?php
//Exclui linhas não ativadas em até 24h
function vinte_e_quatro () {     
$tempo_agora = time(); 
$query = DBDrop('myway', "ativo='0' AND (data_ts + 86400) <= '$tempo_agora' "); 
}
$revisa = vinte_e_quatro();
?>
```

Devo fazer um cron job para a página onde criei esta função e pronto?
É só esperar que ele rode automaticamente...

Comment: Cron job é a melhor alternativa para isso.

Comment: Acabei de ler aqui, é o que preciso mesmo, mas tenho que ver como aplicar.

Comment: isso vai depender de onde você está hospedando

Comment: Eu usei tanto com meu domínio quanto só o nome do arquivo: www.meusite.com.br/vinte_e_quatro.php ou vinte_e_quatro.php e não consegui, chega no horário programado e a função não executa a não ser que eu acesse o link no browser. Olhe como é o gerenciador: goo.gl/WKKicP

Answer (score 1):

Caso seu servidor tiver CPANEL, você pode configurar um "cronjob", só procurar no painel e configurar de quanto em quanto tempo deve ser executado o arquivo ou url, e utilizaria algo do tipo:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://seusite.com.br/arquivo.php
```

Comment: Eu usei tanto com meu domínio quanto só o nome do arquivo: www.meusite.com.br/vinte_e_quatro.php   ou vinte_e_quatro.php    e não consegui, chega no horário programado e a função não executa a não ser que eu acesse o link no browser.

Comment: Olhe como é o gerenciador: http://goo.gl/WKKicP

Comment: Este é o cpanel do meu servidor: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1350/tmDKCo.png

Comment: Esse 'curl -s -o /dev/null" no comando é de seu cpanel ou temos que usar em qualquer cron job?

Comment: Sendo que o seu servidor tenha a biblioteca CURL habilitada, você consegue utiliza-la, "/dev/null" é apenas para não enviar emails para você a cada vez que o cron for executado, tente executar o arquivo pelo caminho do mesmo, ex.: /home/SEU-USUARIO/public_html/nome-do-arquivo.php. Caso não funcione mesmo assim, tente dessa forma: wget http://seudominio.com/arquivo.php

Comment: Cara, tentei de todas as formas e nada, Encontrei até isso: http://goo.gl/OC2up8  No final deste fórum o cara diz que  eu teria que criar um outro arquivo para chamar meu script. Fiz isso e nada. Também estou em um servidor gratuito, estou usando para fazer testes, então vai que tá bugado mesmo...

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que o seu código já esta funcionando corretamente, você pode incluir esta query no inicio da pagina inicial do site, por exemplo:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';  
require 'connection.php'; 
require 'database.php'; 

//Exclui linhas não ativadas em até 24h
$query = DBDrop('myway', "ativo='0' AND (data_ts + 86400) <= '" . time() . "' "); 

// restante o seu código.
// ...
```

Não tem problema em executar essa query em todas as requisições, a menos que a sua base de dados tenha milhões de registros é claro...

E considere indexar os campos ativo e data_ts se a tabela tiver muitos campos.

---

Se precisar configurar a tarefa com uma cronjob, tente com o comando abaixo:

```
35 20 * * * lynx -dump http://dominio/arquivo.php
```

Neste exemplo, ela é executada todos os dias as 20:35

Comment: Já estava assim no "default.php" mesmo. Eu imagino que não tenha problemas que isso rode toda vez que a página for acessada, mas fiquei curioso e quero testar o cron job, pois pode ser útil em outros casos. Grato!

Comment: Como indexar? E qual utilidade?

Comment: @IWannaKnow editar a estrutura da tabela no banco de dados e colocar com campos como index, a busca das informações fica mais rápida...

Comment: Consegui add index ao campo, mas já que isso torna a consulta mais rápida por que não indexar todos os campos? Tem que escolher os mais importantes ou coisa do tipo?

Comment: @IWannaKnow A ideia básica é indexar apenas campos que vão ser usados em clausulas where, ou seja dados que vão ser pesquisados/comparados durante a consulta, mas é aconselhável realizar testes de performance antes de depois de indexar, pois pode ocorrer de uma consulta ficar mais lenta com um determinado campo indexado.

Comment: Entendo, grato.

Comment: @IWannaKnow Editei a resposta e inclui uma opção de comando para usar na cronjob, tente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar cron job, como o pessoal comentou. Ou também uma opção que você pode fazer para não executar todas as vezes o mesmo código quando alguém abrir a sua página:

- Pode ser feito sempre que alguém ativar uma conta, por exemplo, você exclui todos os registros do banco de dados que tenham sido efetuados a mais de 24 horas. Podendo utilizar essa verificação por exemplo:

  `date_add(data_ts, interval 1 day) <= now() and ativo = 0`

A qual irá adicionar 1 dia em "data_ts" e caso o resultado for menor que a data/hora atual, exclui do banco de dados.